# Win_ros hydro tutorial problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been following the win_ros (hydro) documentation without issue until I reach step 4.1 on the "Msvc SDK Messages" page(Sorry, not enough karma to post the link!). When I try to run "winros_create_msg_pkg custom_msgs" I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\opt\ros\hydro\x86\bin\winros_create_msg_
from winros_create_msg_pkg import create_winros
ImportError: No module named winros_create_msg_pkg

I'm completely new to this but I've been asked to get familiar with win_ros specifically. Has anyone had a similar problem or have any idea what I maybe missing?

Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80876/win_ros-hydro-tutorial-problem/) by [Astaples](https://answers.ros.org/users/6876/astaples/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Astaples,

I'm in the process of figuring out WinROS for myself.  A word of warning - the WinROS documentation is very incomplete and the results of the code generation scripts and intended operation do not exactly mirror the standard Ubuntu installation (which further confuses things).

Regarding your issue, when you launch a new command prompt, you have to use the following first:

call C:\opt\ros\hydro\x86\setup.bat

This sets up all of your temporary paths and environment variables.  I also had an issue getting things to build from the command line (cl.exe couldn't be found).  If you have all ready solved this issue, great.  If you haven't, here is the solution that worked for me:

cl.exe problem - add the path to cl.exe to your windows environment variables; if this gives you another error about a .dll missing, there was an executable that you'll need to run.  I don't recall the specific executable but it shows up on a Google search pretty quickly.

Hope that helps you.

- Chief

---

Originally posted by [Chief_534](https://answers.ros.org/users/5677/chief_534/) with karma: 31 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0